# Self-Hosted Calender System for Scheduling Appointments based on Timeslots, similar to 'Calendly'

Tags: php, calendar, mysql, self-hosted, scheduling

Is there a free, open source appointment scheduling-system similar to *Calendly* where I can predetermine timeslots for others to choose?

And if one person selected a timeslot, then that timeslot is visible as reserved or blocked for others.

I would like to have a self-hosted alternative to *Calendly*, perhaps based on PHP/MySQL.

I already tried [Easy!Appointments](https://github.com/alextselegidis/easyappointments), but a "[dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)" (via *NodeJS* / *npm*) made me download an additional 32.000 documents (!), which in turn led to errors during the more-than-an-hour-long FTP upload, which ultimately meant that I could not use it.

Comment: Re Easy!Appointments, did you try using "composer" to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Another system to look at is [BookedScheduler](https://github.com/effgarces/BookedScheduler). This link is for the last open source version, as it has now become a SaaS. It will probably have more than you require, but if configured properly can do the job. Also see a demo [here](https://demo.bookedscheduler.com/Web/)